# How to re-insert a single-hung window into the frame over the guide rods?

Tags: windows

UPDATE: window is fixed! The solution is here: youtube.com/watch?v=-TAjm4X8ubI

---

I have a single-hung Madison window. The moving part has come loose and disassembled and I can't get it back in.

There are two rods that fit into spaces at the sides of the window frame. (See links to images below, but I will try to describe them.)

These rods are notched and there is a combination of a spring and a cord inside the notch. At the top ,the cord is fastened to a a little doo-dad that inserts into a hole in the larger window frame and anchors it there.

These rods act like rails when the window slides up and down.

I can fit the window into place if the rods are not there. And I can put the rods in place if the window is not there. But I can't get them both in at the same time. Do the rods go in first? Does the window? Do I put the rods in the window slots first?
There's no give in the jamb and with the rods in place the window is too big.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i3dS.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8awrK.jpg]

Comment: Can you insert the window first and then slide the rod down into the slot from above?

Comment: Is it possible that if you remove the storm window and screen that it would sneak into place easier from the outward side?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. One photo which I couldn`t post shows that the top of the window is capped-- I can`t get into it. The cap contains the locking mechanism. And no, getting to it from the outside won`t work either. Good idea, though.

Comment: One last thought... Is it possible to place the window in first, push it up to the top and then work the slide mechanism in from the bottom? You may have to adjust the slide into its working mode (extend, pull part out etc) for an up window position for this technique to work. It is difficult to visualize more how your mechanisms work without more pictures of it. :-(

Comment: Can you temporarily post additional pictures to some other place on the web and add a link to your question?

Comment: The window is fixed! The solution is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TAjm4X8ubI .

Comment: My Googling mistake was to think that the window is really a Madison window. Madison is just a local "repackager" -- they retail other people's windows. When I took "Madison" out of the search terms, I got an answer.

Comment: @Len Would you mind adding the solution as an answer, so that future users can learn from your experience? A brief description of the process and a link to the video, might be helpful to somebody else having the same problem as you.